# Create a generic function

Tags: javascript

I've got a load of very similar functions that do different things I'm trying to refactor this. Below I've created a `generic_command`:

```
function generic_command(name, run){
  var start_position = $('textarea').prop('selectionStart'),
      end_position = $('textarea').prop('selectionEnd'),
      current_command = { command : name, last_start_position : start_position, last_end_position : end_position }

  if(current_command == last_command){

    original_content = $('textarea').val()

    run // different code needs to be executed here!

    last_command = current_command

  }
}
```

Literally the only thing that changes in the function is the code that is run at `run`.

I tried to call it like this:

```
$('#remove_bold').bind('click', function(){
  generic_command('remove_bold', remove_character(start_position), remove_character(end_position - 2 ))
});
```

However, this doesn't work as `start_position` and `end` position are undefined when called by the listener.

I'm guessing it would work if I evaluated `run` as in `eval(run)`, but I don't want to use `eval` as this is insecure.

Should I create a generic_command class and make instances of it? How should I do that? Could I have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a callback function:

```
function generic_command(name, run){
    var start_position = $('textarea').prop('selectionStart'),
        end_position = $('textarea').prop('selectionEnd'),
        current_command = { command : name, last_start_position : start_position, last_end_position : end_position };
    if(current_command == last_command){
        original_content = $('textarea').val();
        run(start_position, end_position);
        last_command = current_command;
    }
}

generic_command("remove_bold", function(start_position, end_position) {
    remove_character(start_position), remove_character(end_position - 2 );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem by thinking functionally. The approach you can use is to pass in a function that takes the needed values as parameters, and then executes on them whatever you need. Like this:

```
// run should be a function that takes a command object as its parameter
function generic_command(name, run) {
    var start_position = $('textarea').prop('selectionStart'),
        end_position = $('textarea').prop('selectionEnd'),
        current_command = { 
            command: name, 
            start_position: start_position, 
            end_position: end_position 
        };

    if (current_command == last_command) {    
        original_content = $('textarea').val();

        run(current_command);

        last_command = current_command;    
    }
}
```

Then you can implement your event handler like this:

```
$('#remove_bold').bind('click', function(){
    generic_command('remove_bold', function(command) {
        remove_character(command.start_position);
        remove_character(command.end_position - 2 );
    });
});
```

Incidentally, I think you still have a logic issue here because in the above function `current_command == last_command` will always be `false`.

Comment: Maybe too advanced for this level of question, but if this function was also curried, it could be even nicer.  `var remove_bold = generic_command('remove_bold'); /* ... */ $('#remove_bold').bind('click', remove_bold(function(command) { /* ... */}));`

Comment: So the `run` function should basically contain an extensive `case` loop to run certain code? I get that but I haven't really seen that behaviour anywhere (I'll admit I don't do much javascript)...is this the best way to do it? I'd rather uproot everything and do it the right way than carry on doing it wrong...

Comment: Nobody said anything about an extensive `case` loop. `run` is a function that you pass into `generic_function` and it would be diferent in each situation. In the example above, the run function being passed in is `function(command) { remove_character(command.start_position); remove_character(command.end_position - 2 ); }`. For a different event, you would pass in a _different_ `run` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to run code like that, it is termed a "callback". In order to use it properly, when passing it in you usually test to make sure it is a function, and then execute the function.

```
function myFunc(run){
 if($.isFunction(run))run() //since jQuery is already included in the post above
}
```

In order to pass a function that can be used in this way, you should use an anonymous function

```
myFunc(function(){ alert("hello");})
```

In your case, there is something a little more complex because you are expecting to call this function with variables existing inside of the function. In this case, you should pass in the function handle, and then call it with the arguments

pass the handle

```
$('#remove_bold').bind('click', function(){
 generic_command('remove_bold', remove_character)
});
```

use the handle inside of `function generic_command`

```
run(start_position);
run(end_position - 2 );
```